# inline image drops below span element filled with text (both are inside <li> in a list)

Tags: layout, css

I came upon strange situation. I have a List and each list item consists of span and image element. They are both inline and as long as span is empty they are next to each other, but when span has text, image acts as if it was display:block and falls underneath the span element which is not my desired effect. (I fill span with text dynamically)

```
 <ul id="playerListInsideRoom">
    <li class="playerCircleInsideRoom circleFull" seatnumber="1">
        <img src="~/Images/Lobby/successGray.png" alt="image" /><span>    </span></li>
    <li class="playerCircleInsideRoom circleEmpty" seatnumber="2">
        <img src="~/Images/Lobby/successGray.png" alt="image" /><span></span></li>
    <li class="playerCircleInsideRoom circleEmpty" seatnumber="3">
        <img src="~/Images/Lobby/successGray.png" alt="image" /><span></span></li>
    <li class="playerCircleInsideRoom circleEmpty" seatnumber="4">
        <img src="~/Images/Lobby/successGray.png" alt="image" /><span></span></li>
</ul>

 .playerCircleInsideRoom span{
 position:relative;
 left:50px;
 }

 #playerListInsideRoom img {
 height:15px;
 width:15px; 
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 right:40px;
 }
```

Even when I get rid of relative positions the problem is still occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the width of inline elements is larger than the allowed width of the container (your `li` element) then the line will break.

You could use `whitespace: nowrap`  on the `li` to prevent it (though that could possibly break the rest of your layout).

Comment: He also could extend the width of the list.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that I do set the with of li shorter than its children width, that was my mistake :)